# Vectorize an algorithm with numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an two arrays of 1's and 0's:

```
a = [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
b = [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
```

I want to make sure that the "1" always "jumps" the array as I go from left to right never appearing in the same array twice in a row before appearing in the other array.

```
a = [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
b = [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

I can do it using pandas and iteration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": a, "B": b, })
df2 = df[(df.A > 0) | (df.B > 0)]
i = 0
for idx in df2.index:
    try:       
        if df2.at[idx, 'A'] == df2.at[df2.index[i + 1], 'A']:
            df.at[idx, 'A'] = 0
        if df2.at[idx, 'B'] == df2.at[df2.index[i + 1], 'B']:
            df.at[idx, 'B'] = 0
        i += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

But it is not efficient. How can I vectorize it to make it faster?

Comment: so, you update the arrays if they don't follow the pattern? Or is this some sort of check and you just need to know if it fits the pattern?

Comment: @rawwar I update it, leaving only the last 1

Comment: @Viktor What if the values at the same index equal 1?

Comment: Your example code doesn't work. The indices of `df2` are `0,1,3,4,...` and when `i==2`, it rightfully raises a `KeyError`.

Comment: @AndrejKesely they won't be

Comment: @PierreD I am not sure, what you mean. I tested the code and it works fine for me. ```i``` is used only in indexing, why would it cause a ```KeyError```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```py
df2 = df[(df.A > 0) | (df.B > 0)]
df2 = df2[df2.B != df2.B.shift(-1)]

df.loc[~df.index.isin(df2.index)] = 0
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    A  B
0   1  0
1   0  1
2   0  0
3   1  0
4   0  1
5   0  0
6   0  0
7   0  0
8   0  0
9   0  0
10  0  0
11  0  0
12  1  0
13  0  0
14  0  0
15  0  0
16  0  0
17  0  0
18  0  0
19  0  1
```

---

EDIT: Step by-step explanation:

Keep only indices where there is `1` value anywhere in row:

```
df2 = df[(df.A > 0) | (df.B > 0)]
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
    A  B
0   1  0
1   0  1
3   1  0
4   0  1
9   1  0
16  0  1
19  0  1
```

We see that we want only the indices where there's a alternating changes between A and B (so we need to get rid of the index `16` here).

We know that `B` must alternate, so we shift the `B` column and compare:

```py
df2["tmp"] = df2.B != df2.B.shift(-1)

    A  B    tmp
0   1  0   True
1   0  1   True
3   1  0   True
4   0  1   True
9   1  0   True
16  0  1  False
19  0  1   True
```

Index `16` has `False` value, so we keep only the other indices:

```py
df2 = df2[df2.B != df2.B.shift(-1)]
df.loc[~df.index.isin(df2.index)] = 0
print(df)
```

Prints the final df.

Comment: @Nick I've added short explanation.

Comment: Thanks - it makes a lot more sense with the explanation.